# Making A Function Recursive

Tags: c#, recursion

the following function needs to look inside the input object if there is a property in it that returns a custom object it needs to do the trimming of that object as well. The code below works for the input object fine, but wont recursively look into a property that returns a custom object and do the trimming process.

```
public object TrimObjectValues(object instance)
{
    var props = instance.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                // Ignore non-string properties
                .Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(string) | prop.PropertyType == typeof(object))
                // Ignore indexers
                .Where(prop => prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
                // Must be both readable and writable
                .Where(prop => prop.CanWrite && prop.CanRead);

    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
    {
        if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            string value = (string)prop.GetValue(instance, null);
            if (value != null)
            {
                value = value.Trim();
                prop.SetValue(instance, value, null);
            }
        }
        else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(object))
        {
            TrimObjectValues(prop);
        }
    }

    return instance;
}
```

I need to change this somehow to look for other objects inside the initial object

```
.Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(string) | prop.PropertyType == typeof(object))
```

This code isn't working reason is for a example is the object I am passing as input has a property that returns a type of "Address" therefore typeof(object) never gets hit.

Here is a tree of data to test against pass the function "o" in this case

```
        Order o = new Order();

    o.OrderUniqueIdentifier = "TYBDEU83e4e4Ywow";

    o.VendorName = "Kwhatever";
    o.SoldToCustomerID = "Abc98971";
    o.OrderType = OrderType.OnOrBefore;
    o.CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber = "MOOMOO 56384";
    o.EmailAddress = "abc@electric.com";
    o.DeliveryDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(35);

    Address address1 = new Address();
    //address1.AddressID = "Z0mmn01034";
    address1.AddressID = "E0000bbb6                         ";
    address1.OrganizationName = "                                       Nicks Organization ";
    address1.AddressLine1 = "              143 E. WASHINGTON STREET                ";
    address1.City = "          Rock        ";
    address1.State = "MA                       ";
    address1.ZipCode = "                         61114";
    address1.Country = "US                ";

    o.ShipToAddress = address1;
```

Comment: @Darin no unfortunately it still doesnt understand to filter custom objects. I need a generic way to do this.

Comment: What defines a "custom object"? Why don't you just take off the condition for the "else if" case?

Comment: I have an object for example called Address it holds Address data. I have an object called Order in Order there is a property called orderAddress that returns of type Address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tests with `typeof(object)` will all fail.

Try like this:

```
static void TrimObjectValues(object instance)
{
    // if the instance is null we have nothing to do here
    if (instance == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var props = instance
        .GetType()
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
        // Ignore indexers
        .Where(prop => prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
        // Must be both readable and writable
        .Where(prop => prop.CanWrite && prop.CanRead);

    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
    {
        if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            // if we have a string property we trim it
            string value = (string)prop.GetValue(instance, null);
            if (value != null)
            {
                value = value.Trim();
                prop.SetValue(instance, value, null);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // if we don't have a string property we recurse
            TrimObjectValues(prop.GetValue(instance, null));
        }
    }
}
```

I have also made the function return no value because you are modifying the argument instance anyway.

Test case:

```
public enum OrderType
{
    OnOrBefore
}

public class Order
{
    public string OrderUniqueIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string VendorName { get; set; }
    public string SoldToCustomerID { get; set; }
    public OrderType OrderType { get; set; }
    public string CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public Address ShipToAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string AddressID { get; set; }
    public string OrganizationName { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Order o = new Order();

        o.OrderUniqueIdentifier = "TYBDEU83e4e4Ywow";

        o.VendorName = "Kwhatever";
        o.SoldToCustomerID = "Abc98971";
        o.OrderType = OrderType.OnOrBefore;
        o.CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber = "MOOMOO 56384";
        o.EmailAddress = "abc@electric.com";
        o.DeliveryDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(35);

        Address address1 = new Address();
        //address1.AddressID = "Z0mmn01034";
        address1.AddressID = "E0000bbb6                         ";
        address1.OrganizationName = "                                       Nicks Organization ";
        address1.AddressLine1 = "              143 E. WASHINGTON STREET                ";
        address1.City = "          Rock        ";
        address1.State = "MA                       ";
        address1.ZipCode = "                         61114";
        address1.Country = "US                ";

        o.ShipToAddress = address1;


        TrimObjectValues(o);
    }

    static void TrimObjectValues(object instance)
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var props = instance
            .GetType()
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            // Ignore indexers
            .Where(prop => prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
            // Must be both readable and writable
            .Where(prop => prop.CanWrite && prop.CanRead);

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                string value = (string)prop.GetValue(instance, null);
                if (value != null)
                {
                    value = value.Trim();
                    prop.SetValue(instance, value, null);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                TrimObjectValues(prop.GetValue(instance, null));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE 2:

It seems that you want to handle also lists of objects. You could adapt the method:

```
static void TrimObjectValues(object instance)
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var props = instance
        .GetType()
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
        // Ignore indexers
        .Where(prop => prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
        // Must be both readable and writable
        .Where(prop => prop.CanWrite && prop.CanRead);

    if (instance is IEnumerable)
    {
        foreach (var element in (IEnumerable)instance)
        {
            TrimObjectValues(element);
        }
        return;
    }

    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
    {
        if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            string value = (string)prop.GetValue(instance, null);
            if (value != null)
            {
                value = value.Trim();
                prop.SetValue(instance, value, null);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TrimObjectValues(prop.GetValue(instance, null));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: They won't fail when he has a class that has a property of Type object (but he won't ever even get a chance to execute the else statement because of the .Where() clause above).

Comment: I am getting a nullRefereneeException with this code....Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @NickLaMarca, I have updated my answer in order to test if the instance is null in the beginning of the method. Also it might help if you actually showed the object tree you are testing with along with sample values.

Comment: @Darin Its not throwing any exceptions now but it still will not trim anything besides strings in the top level. So in my case its not looking inside the orderAddress property which is of type Address and trimming all the strings in the properties of the Address. It does trim all the strings in the input type Order but wont do the "recursive" action

Comment: @NickLaMarca, sorry, I am unable to reproduce the issue. I have updated my answer with an example. I invite you to the same with your question and provide your object tree and sample values.

Comment: @Darin I updated the question with sample input data. I am still not able to get the recursive action with the function you provided

Comment: @NickLaMarca, and I have updated my answer with your test values and the function works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Darin I apologize, this works ok, where its failing on my end is another property is returning a List<OrderItems> the function doesnt know how to handle a List of type someCustomObject

Comment: @NickLaMarca, see my second update which allows to handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

`prop.PropertyType == typeof(object)` does not work, because this will only be true for `object` and not for derived types. You would have to write `typeof(object).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType)`; however, this applies for all the types! Drop both conditions (for `string` and for `object`).

Note: Also drop the condition before the `TrimObjectValues(prop);`. (Replace `else if (...)` by `else`)

Comment: Won't he get an exception when he tries to cast a custom object to a string in this case ((string)prop.GetValue(instance, null))?

Comment: The test for string before trimming is ok, only the test after `else` is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

```
public object TrimObjectValues(object instance)
{
    if (instance is string)
    {
        instance = ((string)instance).Trim();

        return instance;
    }

    if (instance is IEnumerable)
    {
        foreach (var element in (IEnumerable)instance)
        {
            TrimObjectValues(element);
        }

        return instance;
    }

    var props = instance.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            // Ignore non-string properties
            .Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(string) | prop.PropertyType is object)
            // Ignore indexers
            .Where(prop => prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
            // Must be both readable and writable
            .Where(prop => prop.CanWrite && prop.CanRead);

    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
    {
        if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            string value = (string)prop.GetValue(instance, null);
            if (value != null)
            {
                value = value.Trim();
                prop.SetValue(instance, value, null);
            }
        }
        else if (prop.PropertyType is object)
        {
            TrimObjectValues(prop.GetValue(instance, null));
        }
    }

    return instance;
}
```